How to convert all PPT text blocks to another language using in-built Translator through Python code?
I need help on how to perform PPT in-built language translation through Python code.
I need to convert the text in PPT into a different language.
Rather than using external translator modules, need to use in-built translator and do language translation..
I have 200 PPTs to convert and hence need to do it via code. So are there py modules for msoffice or any other way I can use this in-built translator to convert this 200 PPTs into preferred language using Python.


The role of python-pptx could be twofold:


Extracting the text from a PPTX (not PPT).


Placing the translated text into a new PPTX (not PPT).


The translation has to be done some other way.
